# Get a copy of a telegram message - Python

Tags: python, message, telegram

I am trying to find a python library working with the Telegram API which has a method of retrieving a message from a channel and convert it to plain text in order to work on it.

Anyone heard of something that might do the job ? Been browsing the Telegram Bot API and other posts, but did not find anything fitting.

Thanks in advance, buddies.

Answer (score 0):

You need a handler function that gets the message event as a parameter. There you can get the message from the event argument. You can check if the message is a specific command if you're using the Bot API. It is going to look something like this:

```
def handler(event):
    try:
        msg = event["Input"]["message"]["text"]
    except KeyError as error:
        LOGGER.error("ERROR: No message text!")
        return None
```

Comment: Thanks ! But how can my bot listen to the messages of the channel ?

Comment: I used a AWS Lambda function, set your bot handler function as your lambda handler.